# Typescript typeof class and derived classes

Tags: typescript

I have a base class which is extended by several child classes. Now I want to have the type of the parent class as the type of a property. All child types should be valid aswell. I have tried typeof but that doesn't work. Any ideas on how to have the type of a base class as the type for a property? The reason why I want a reference to the type is that I want to be able to create new instances of the Class, for example new test.componentType() should create a new instance of Child2

```
class Parent {

}

class Child1 extends Parent {

}

class Child2 extends Parent {

}

interface Config {
    componentType: typeof Parent;
}

const test: Config = {
    componentType: typeof Child2
}

new test.componentType() -> should create a new instance of Child2
```

Comment: there's no need to use typeof, just use Parent

Comment: Within any class, you can just use `this.constructor.prototype` to get parent class. It's not clear from your question why you need to have that property defined in the interface.

Comment: Edited the question now

Comment: Another word of advice: writing "doesn't work" should trigger an alarm. Prefer stating exactly why it doesn't work, including the compiler's error messages.

Comment: I know, sorry about that. I was really frustrated about the problem and cheated a bit... I should have taken more time to reproduce the error in isolation because the error messages I got was not really helpful in this scenario since it was to much "noise" in them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code was not working because `Child2` is already the class object, which is compatible with `typeof Parent`. `test` should have been defined like this:

```
const test: Config = {
    componentType: Child2
}
```

Nevertheless, you seem to just want the field `componentType` to hold a constructor. In that case, you can make `componentType` prototyped as an object with the `new` method:

```
interface Config {
    componentType: { new(): Parent };
}

const test: Config = {
    componentType: Child2
}

const myinstance: Parent = new test.componentType();
```

To retain information about the constructed instance types, a generic type 
 can be used:

```
interface Config<T extends Parent> {
    componentType: { new(): T };
}

const test = {
    componentType: Child2
}

const myinstance: Child2 = new test.componentType();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a really good answer :) { new (...args): Parent }; solved it.

Comment: Indeed, you need `(...args)` to capture constructors with non-empty parameter lists.

Comment: Do I understand that correctly? There is a difference between how INSTANCE _(a)_ and CLASS CONSTRUCTOR _(B)_ are typed. This should be ultimately correct then, _right?_ - `class A {}; const B: {new(): A} = A; const a: A = new B()`