# typescript typeof subclass of React.Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a base class which extends `React.Component` and is extended by several child classes. Now I want to have the type of the `Parent` class as the type of a property, and all `Child` classes should be valid for the property. I had a try of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653343/typescript-typeof-class-and-derived-classes), but it doesn't work when `Parent` extends `React.Component`.

```
class Parent extends React.Component{}
class Child1 extends Parent {}
class Child2 extends Parent {}
type F = {
  cp: { new(): Parent }
}
let f: F = {
  cp: Child1 //type 'typeof Child' is not assignable to type 'new () => Parent'.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor signatures mandates that the type have an empty constructor, but the constructor inherited from `React.Component` has two parameters. This is why `typeof Child` is not assignable to `new ()=> Parent`. You need to specify the constructor takes these arguments:

```
class Parent extends React.Component { }
class Child1 extends Parent { }
type F = {
    cp: { new(props: any, context?: any): Parent }
}
let f: F = {
    cp: Child1 //ok
}
```

Comment: @zenggo if this answer helped you solved it don't forget to mark as answered :)